# Converting from dd.mm.yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using Excel 2010 and I have a column that contains date in such format (dd.mm.yyyy). I would like to change the dots to slash (/). I have tried using `rng.Cells(1, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(rng.Cells(1, 6), ". ", "/")`

However, when I do that, the result I get is different from my original date. For example, 02.11.2011 will become 11/02/2011.

The column that contains (dd.mm.yyyy) is in a `date` format

May I know why is that or is there another way of doing?

Comment: Do you have an actual date value, or a string that represents a date? They're not the same thing. If you have an actual date, then you shouldn't be treating it as a string at all, but should be using `numberformat` to change the formatting (as you would with Format Cells in the UI - in fact, you can record a macro doing just that and get Excel to write the code for you).

Comment: @Ken White Hi, yes the column format itself is a date.

Answer (score 0):

Is the column formatted as a date?  If so, you can try

```
rng.Cells(1, 6) = Format(CDate(rng.Cells(1, 6)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: I tried this but there was an error stating 'Type mismatched'. Originally, the column (dd.mm.yyyy) is already formatted as date.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an actual date value, then use `NumberFormat`

```
Range("B1").NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
Range("B2").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Range("B3").NumberFormat = "m-d-yyyy"
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not change anything. When I use your line of code together with the one I posted, it still changes my dd to mm and my mm to dd. Eg (11.02.2011 became 02/11/2011)

Comment: The format has meaning. `"d/m/yyyy"` means `day/month/four-digit year`. So April 1, 2019 would be `m/d/yyyy` for `4/1/2019` or `"d/m/yyyy"` for `1/4/2019`. Double the `mm` and `dd` to get two digit months and days (as in `01/04/2019`). In a new Excel workbook, type your date in cell B1 and then copy it down to B3, so that all cells have the same date. Then run the code I posted, and you'll see three different formats for that same date. Pick the one that works for you, or experiment with your own. I've tested the above code, and it works with your sample date.

Answer (score 0):

Im using this

```
splR = Split(oRange.Value, ".")
If UBound(splR) = 2 Then oRange.Value = Format(DateSerial(splR(2), splR(1), splR(0)), RegionalDateFormat) Else oRange.Value = oRange.Value

Function RegionalDateFormat(Optional outS As String)
    Dim DateOrder As String
    Dim DateSeparator As String

With Application
    DateSeparator = .International(xlDateSeparator)
    Select Case .International(xlDateOrder)
        Case Is = 0
            DateOrder = "mm" & DateSeparator & "dd" & DateSeparator & "yyyy"
        Case Is = 1
            DateOrder = "dd" & DateSeparator & "mm" & DateSeparator & "yyyy"
        Case Is = 2
            DateOrder = "yyyy" & DateSeparator & "mm" & DateSeparator & "dd"
        Case Else
            DateOrder = "Error"
    End Select


End With
If outS = "Sep" Then outputS = DateSeparator Else outputS = DateOrder
RegionalDateFormat = outputS

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify that an Excel spreadsheet does not have a "date" data type per se.  Excel's approach to dates is to store an integer, which you can choose to format as a date.  So, for example, 43467 is the integer representing Jan 2 2019. (And the decimal part represents time during that day, so 43467.333.. represents Jan 2 2019 8:00 am.)

Try entering a date, then right-click > "Format cells" to format that cell as a number, to observe what I'm talking about.

In the same way, you can cause Excel to render that cell in the date format you want using the same method: select the cell > right-click > "Format cells", choose Custom, and enter a custom format, like dd.mm.yyyy.

Once you see that works, then your remaining task is simply to perform that same action from VBA, which would be with a statement like:

Range("B1").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"

... as pointed out by others.

Now, if your initial attempt to get Excel to format your date cell as a number fails (it maintains its date appearance) then the date you see in the cell is actually stored as a string, and won't function as a date (for example to do date arithmetic). So you'll need to decide how to proceed -- perhaps convert these strings to "dates" (ie: numbers formatted as dates).